# Neo4j : How to create a unique node instead of set of nodes

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a new node (`event nodes`) among a set of nodes (`report nodes`) according to the `indicator nodes` (each report node has several indicator nodes related to it). I want to set the new `event nodes` with the rules:

1. a `report nodes` is only connected one `event node`
2. if more than one `indicator nodes` has the same property "pattern", then they belong to the same event node

here are my query code :

```
OPTIONAL MATCH 
(indicator_1_1:indicator)<-[:REFERS_TO]-(report_1:report)-[:REFERS_TO]->(indicator_1_2:indicator),
(indicator_2_1:indicator)<-[:REFERS_TO]-(report_2:report)-[:REFERS_TO]->(indicator_2_2:indicator)
WHERE
indicator_1_1.pattern=indicator_2_1.pattern
and
indicator_1_2.pattern=indicator_2_2.pattern
MERGE
(report_1)-[:related_to]->(event:EVENT)<-[:related_to]-(report_2)
```

and get the result as below,
[image]

But i want the three report nodes belong to one  event node.
I want to know what changes should I make to my query ,or what next step should I take after getting the two event nodes.

What's more , I want to know wheter there is a more efficient query code than mine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `(:indicator {pattern:})` assigned in such a way that unambiguous unique `:event` nodes would be expected?

Comment: yes, in another way to express, the :event nodes are set to conclude the :indicator nodes

Comment: What happens if you split the `MERGE` into two?  I.e., `MERGE (report_1)-[:related_to]->(event:EVENT)` `MERGE (event)<-[:related_to]-(report_2)`.

Comment: the split  method would get the similar result ,but after the two step below, they can be well solved

Comment: So using the two `MERGE` statements produces the result you are looking for?

Comment: yes, it answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any data to confirm, but I think a small change to your Cypher query will produce what you want.

From the Neo4j Cypher Manual chapter on [`MERGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/index.html) (my emphasis added).

> When using `MERGE` on full patterns, the behavior is that either the
>   whole pattern matches, or the whole pattern is created. `MERGE` will
>   not partially use existing patterns — **it’s all or nothing**. If
>   partial matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a
>   pattern up into multiple `MERGE` clauses.

So, following this, I think if you change

```
MERGE (report_1)-[:related_to]->(event:EVENT)<-[:related_to]-(report_2)
```

to

```
MERGE (report_1)-[:related_to]->(event:EVENT)
MERGE (event)<-[:related_to]-(report_2)
```

... you will prevent the extra `:EVENT` nodes from being created and get the graph you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the answer. My solution is  merge the :event node ,and then  the relaionships

step 1 : merge the :event nodes

```
MATCH ()-[r_1:related_to]->(event_1:EVENT)<-[r_2:related_to]-()-[r_3:related_to]->(event_2:EVENT)<-[r_4:related_to]-()
call apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([event_1,event_2]) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

step 2 : merge the dupicate relationships

```
MATCH (X)-[r]-(Y)
WITH X,Y, TAIL (collect(r)) as rr
FOREACH (r IN rr | DELETE r)
```